# Covariance of normal variate and T statistic

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, covariance

If $\overline{X}$ and $S^2$ be the usual sample mean and sample variance based in a random sample of $n$ observation $N(\mu,\sigma^{2})$ and $T=\frac{(\overline{X}-\mu) \sqrt{n}}{S}$
`  prove that $Cov(\overline{X}, T)=\sigma\frac{\sqrt{n-1}\Gamma\left(\frac{n-2}{2}\right)}{\sqrt{2n}\Gamma\left(\frac{n-1}{2}\right)}$.

I tried to solve the question using expectation but I don't have any idea about how to proceed further, can someone please help in proving  it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, $\bar{X}_n$ and $S_n$ are independent (see, e.g., [Basu's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basu%27s_theorem#Independence_of_sample_mean_and_sample_variance_of_a_normal_distribution_(known_variance))). Then
$$
\mathsf{E}\bar{X}_n(\bar{X}_n-\mu)/S_n=\operatorname{Var}(\bar{X}_n)\times \mathsf{E}S_n^{-1}=\frac{\sigma^2}{n}\times \frac{\sqrt{n-1}}{\sqrt{2}\sigma}\frac{\Gamma((n-2)/2)}{\Gamma((n-1)/2)}
$$
because $\sigma S_n^{-1}/\sqrt{n-1}\sim\chi_{n-1}^{-1}$. Also note that $\mathsf{E}T_n=0$. Therefore,
$$
\operatorname{Cov}(\bar{X}_n,T_n)=\frac{\sigma\sqrt{n-1}}{\sqrt{2n}}\frac{\Gamma((n-2)/2)}{\Gamma((n-1)/2)}.
$$

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more on how did you reach the last step, thanks a lot

Comment: The expectation of the inverse $\chi$ distribution is known. See, for example, [this note](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/bayesian-statistics-an/9781118359778/OEBPS/c1-sec1-0006.htm) (though, there are missing parentheses).

Comment: Thanks a lot, that really helped me